# Phonegap 2.8.0 and BB10 Error initializing Cordova: Extension device not found on app launch

Tags: cordova, runtime-error, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am getting started with BB10 an Phonegap 2.8.0. I am taking the starter app that phonegap builds and building an deploying it to my BB10 device. When the app launches on the device I get the following error:

[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Extension Device not found

Has anyone else experienced this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to troubleshoot just from a screenshot :)

Looks like this is just the sample app.  Did you modify any of the code at all, or just packaged it right out of the box?  I know the sample does work, we've tested here at the (BlackBerry) office.

Comment: Simply packaged right out of the box. I was trying to isolate why this error occurs on launch and whether it has any impact on accessing any Phonegap JS APIs.